# How to Add a Button Click event on Controller of EXTJS MVC

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to develop an application using Ext JS. so far I have developed a Viewport with border layout and I have north region, south region done. in the center region i have multiple panel such 1. for search the data. 2. input the data task list (a form) and on the next panel to this I have displayed the grid. Following to that panel I have a Button which should listen to click event to brought up the form to the user.

For that event handeling my controller looks like this:

```
    this.control({
       'viewport button [action=add]':{
    click: this. addData},
addData : function(button){
consol.log('the add button was clicked');
}
    .......
```

Now if i click the button in the page where the button has been displayed its not responding anything
following is the structure code i have for the viewport:

```
launch : function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout : 'border',
        autoScroll : true,
        items : [{
            region: 'north',
            .......
        },{
            region: 'west',
            ..............
        },{
            region: 'center',
            items:[{
                xtype: 'panel',
                ..............
            },{
                xtype: 'panel',
                ............
            },{
                xtype: 'userlist' 
            },{
                xtype: 'button',
                 text: 'Add',
                 action: 'add'
            }]
        }]
```

Any help would be highly Appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between `button` and `[action=add]` in your selector:

```
this.control({
   'viewport button[action=add]': {
        click: this. addData
    },
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Was a great help. And also I need to write the controller which brings up a user information entry form instead of logging out the console message. So far I have defined a SearchForm in my view and gave an alias as searchform. my guess was i would pass that searchForm to to the addData but tough luck so,  I wonder How could I do that. if you still could help it would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to get a reference to your form from the `addData()` function? You can use the same selector-based approach using `Ext.ComponentQuery`, something like `button.up('panel').down('searchform')`.  There is a ton of flexibility with them, especially if you add `itemId` to your components and do `button.up('#myParentPanel')`, etc.  Check out the docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery